# Get values of all selected items from user-created select fields

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select field with a add button next to it inside a form. The user will click the add button and create as many extra select fields as he wants and then select an item from each of the select fields. When he submits the form, I want the values of all selected items in an array.

Can any one help please? Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('../conn.inc.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
function addRow(r){
        var root = r.parentNode;
        var allRows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var cRow = allRows[0].cloneNode(true)
        var cInp = cRow.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i=0;i<cInp.length;i++){
            cInp[i].setAttribute('name',cInp[0].getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1))
        }
        var cSel = cRow.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
        cSel.setAttribute('name',cSel.getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1));
        root.appendChild(cRow);
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form method="get" action="abc()"> 
      <table> 
        <tr> 
          <td> 
          <select  name="product_code" id="product_code">       
           <?php
           $sql= mysql_query("select * from product_table where id > 0 order by product_code");
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
           {
                $pcode = $row['product_code'];
                echo "<option value=\"$row[id]\">".$pcode."</option>";
           }
            ?>      
          </select>
           </td> 
          <td>
          <input name="button" type="button" value="+" onick="addRow(this.parentNode.parentNode)">
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more simple than what you've done.

You should set the `name` attribute of **all your selects** something like `productCode[]` (with the brackets).

PHP will automatically create you an `$_POST['productCode']` variable containing all the values in an array..